# How to define a collection for User Roles and User Details in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

In mysql; I have a two tables named User Roles and User details. Role ID using as foreign key in User details table. How to convert this in Mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

You can have that in same way.I used to follow same pattern

Role schema-

```js
var rolesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'role_name':{type:String},
    'actions':[{type:String}]
})
```

User Schema -

```js
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name : String,
  last_name : String,
  role: String, // OR { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'role'}
})
```

and you can directly use populate of mongoose to fetch role data for this user or manually check it using role as string.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the fundamental structure of schema and its definition in mongodb and how it shall translate from mysql.

Let us see few defintions[image]

if you have two tables as you've given, user roles and user details, your potential mongodb schema shall be as follows

```
{ 
   _id: objectid ("random alphanumeric"),
    username: "John Doe",
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    title: "Manager",
      Role: [
                {
                  id: "Random alphanumeric",
                  type: "Admin"
                }
            ]
}
```

Please also go through the Mongodb documentation for sql db mapping
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Note: here _id refers to your user id.